Show autocomplete options above field
I have following component, which makes use of suggestions (using the Autocomplete class):
return Autocomplete<String>(
  // ...
  fieldViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
            TextEditingController fieldTextEditingController,
            FocusNode focusNode,
            VoidCallback onFieldSubmitted) {
    return TextField(
      // ...
    );
  optionsViewBuilder: (BuildContext context,
            AutocompleteOnSelected<String> onSelected,
            Iterable<String> options) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 4.0,
      child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        color: white,
      ),
      width: 360.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        itemCount: options.length,
        // ...
      )

My goal is to somehow have the options show right above the input field, instead of below is, as this component is placed on the bottom of the page

Use the following argument
optionsViewOpenDirection: OptionsViewOpenDirection.up,

